# Opening rowset for "September$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, import

I'm getting the following error when trying to import an Excel file into my database.

I have tried both importing the data into an existing table, and also letting the Import Wizard create a new table.

When checking the mappings, everything looks good. Any insight into this error would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]
[image]

EDIT: Here is where I am defining the source/destinations:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to import a different worksheet than the one you mapped?

Comment: I am not. The file only has one worksheet in it, and the path is correct.

Comment: Can you show the screen where you define the source file?

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshots of source and destination files.

Comment: It looks like it's missing your full Excel file name, I'd guess because of the space in the path.  Try replacing the spaces with underscores or putting the file name in quotes or brackets.

Comment: This was the correct answer. If you'd like credit for this answer, and you think it would help out other users, Answer the Question so I can denote a correct response. Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is being caused by spaces in the name of your Excel file.  If you replace the spaces with underscores the error will go away.
 Change file name from this:

```
September Bioreference.xlsx
```

to this:

```
September_Bioreference.xlsx
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, which makes this such a **dumb** problem to have and an even **dumber** error message to go with it :@